# Defining the Target Value

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, predictive-modeling, feature-engineering

im new to this community and it always helped me with my concerns, i looked for an answer but didnt find a clear one yet

im working on study for insurance default, the data i received is already giving me the default, the issue here is im trying to predict the default and its represented as 0 and the not default is represented as 1

do i need to convert the values to default as 1 and not default as 0, what is the best practice here?

bearing in mind that the data is unbalanced toward not default (1 currently) also i have a lot features that are minus correlated with the default in the current setup

appreciate the help

Comment: Hello,Could you please try and explain it with an example? As far as i understood issue is  Class/Label= default/NoDefault then default= 1 and NoDefault = 0? and should one change this represenatation?

Comment: 0 and 1 mapping will not impact the result. You can use anyone for it.

Comment: BlackCurrant yes but its the opposite 1= non default, 0= default, should i make them the opposite or i can continue and i want to study the default

Comment: Doesn't Matter.